# Is there a logical fallacy that describes insulting an argument rather than addressing it?

Tags: fallacies, rhetoric

I'm having a net debate and the person is raving about how pathetic my argument is rather than explaining why it is a pathetic argument. I believe its a logical fallacy but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like an [*appeal to ridicule*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appeal_to_ridicule) because it does not involve attacking you personally (so its not *ad hominem*). [*Begging the question*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question#Definition) is another possibly-relevant type of circular argument.